# JS variable scope and script sources

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, script-tag

I have a variable defined in script tags within the head of the document:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
    echo '<script>var userdir = '.$_SESSION['user']->directory.'</script>';
} ?>
```

after that I include several javascript files, one of which includes a function which includes

```
if (type == 'image'){
   var imgElement = elementId.replace(/upload_/, "img_");
   $('#'+imgElement).attr("src", "assets/uploads/"+ userdir +"/images/" + vidfile);
}
```

userdir is defined within the document if I view source, but the image path that comes back is 'undefined'.  shouldn't it be getting the value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Variable Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Comment: It's not even close to being a duplicate. How is a list of examples about javascript variable scope useful to this specific application?

Comment: Please put a little more effort into your questions by providing cleanly indented code. Thanks.

Comment: Damon, we'll need to see the source actually generated by your echo line.

Comment: you're almost certainly getting a javascript error at the point where you try to assign `userdir`.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly need to include quotes around the assignment to userdir.

```
echo '<script>var userdir = "'.$_SESSION['user']->directory.'";</script>';
```

Comment: what exactly am I supposed to be seeing?  The single quotes are PHP quotes, and would not be rendered to the page.

Comment: perhaps he thought you were quoting me directly in the line you included in the answer since it does have double quotes?

Comment: Damon - if this fixed your problem you should accept the answer. Also, do get in the habit of providing the type attribute to the script tag as best practice...

Comment: ah thanks.. i always do when including files, but didn't get in the habit of it for inline (Which i don't do much anyway)

Comment: @Triptych, @Damon - According to Douglas Crawford (http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html) the `type` attribute is only required if you're writing XHTML, and is better left out if writing HTML.  Also, in HTML5, the `type` attribute defaults to `text/javascript` (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-script-element)

Comment: yup @ digitalbath. I was wrong about that still being best practice. Changing my own habits after this post.

Answer (score 0):

Anything defined outside of a function is going to be a global variable. I assume the variable you are defining in the document is such a global variable. That global variable should be available inside of any function. I'm assuming your include files are made of functions. If the global values have actually been defined and you can't access them within the functions or the js files then I would question the order of when things are loading.